# How to add a window to apps I am observing using AccessibilityService?

Tags: android, accessibility

I am developing a floating window, which will be shown on apps I am observing using AccessibilityService.
But I don't want the window shown on other apps.

So I firstly configure the `android:packageNames` property of `<accessibility-service>`. Then find some solutions to check whether user is using apps I configured, like `getRunningTasks`, `getRunningAppProcesses` and `UsageStatsManager`. But they all have some shortcomings.

***The question is:***

Is there any way to check whether apps I configured using Accessibility is foreground currently?

***OR:***

Is there any way to make the window shown on apps I configured using Accessiblity and not shown on other apps?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you specify the packageNames, would you get accessibility events when _other_ apps are in the foreground? If not, then perhaps you can determine the events you receive when your app comes into and exits the foreground.

Comment: Thanks to @ataulm But I just set `android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"`, and see: I can receive event entering the app, but there is no event exiting app.

Comment: Oh well it's my fault, I set `packageNames` to all, and everything goes ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to idea of @ataulm !

I find a perfect way of checking whether my apps are in foreground:

1. set accessibility's `packageName` to all
2. set accessibility's `EventTypes` to `typeAllMask`
3. Java:

   ```
   public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
       if (event == null || event.getSource() == null) {
           return;
       }
       AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
       String className = source.getClassName().toString();
       switch (event.getEventType()) {
           case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED:
               Log.i(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: scrolled");
               break;
           case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED:
               setForegroundApp(event.getPackageName());
               break;
           }
   }

   public static String sForegroundPackageName;
   static final List<String> supportedPackagesName = blablablabla;

   public static void setForegroundApp(CharSequence packageName) {
       if (packageName != null) {
           sForegroundPackageName = packageName.toString();
       }
   }

   // use this to check.
   public static boolean isForeground() {
       return supportedPackagesName.contains(sForegroundPackageName);
   }
   ```